# how to use repository or viewmodel method in onAvitivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent, android-mvvm

I am trying to follow MVVM pattern in android project, I have to call network api `onAcitivityResult` method. According to MVVM repository should interact with network calls and viewmodel should do the interaction between Activity and repository. So if I have to access network api then I have to call viewmodel method in onActivityResult. This is my onActivityResult method:

```
class Profile : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val networkConnectionInterceptor = NetworkConnectionInterceptor(this)
        val api = Api.invoke(networkConnectionInterceptor)
        val repository = UserRepository(api)
        val factory = ProfileViewModelFactory(repository, Photo(""))
        val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(ProfileViewModel::class.java)

        val binding: ActivityProfileBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_profile)

        binding.viewmodel = viewModel
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                when (requestCode) {

                    ImageIntent.CAMERA_REQUEST -> {
                    /*  I want to call Viewmodel method here */
                       viewmodel.onProfileImageUpload(ImageIntent.imageUri)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            toast("Image upload cancelled !")
        }
    }
```

This is the method defined in my viewmodel :

```
    fun onProfileImageUpload(uri: Uri) {
        Coroutines.main{
            try {
                val imageResponse = repository.updateProfileAvatar(
                    ImageUtil.getImageForUpload(
                        uri,
                        "avatar"
                    )
                )
                Log.d("avatar_resonse", "$imageResponse")
            } catch(e : Exception) {}
        }
    }
```

The problem is I have to initialize the viewmodel in `Activity onCreate` method so I cannot have the viewmodel instance in the `onActivityResult`. How do I make a network call from there ?

Comment: make your viewmodel variable lateinit and global

Comment: it is not possible it will not get the context before onCreate method is called, and the values on which viewmodel is dependent using the context

Comment: didn't understood your problem here. onActivityResult will be called after activity is created so you will have context already

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
if(requestCode==your code){
      if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){
           if(data!=null){
               // your api and if you calling image from start activity result get it from data
             }
         }
       }
```

Comment: please look at my viewmodel, I have used repository in viewmodel method, the repository calls the api.